# GoldenDict does not show examples lines

Tags: linux, styles

**Problem**: Couldn't see examples for words usage in GoldenDict (very powerful and popular cross-platform dictionary).
I have met this problem on Linux Mint, but it can be cross-platform.

**Problem core**: in the source code of the articles pages I have found that  tags are used as block elements without correct style formatting, so the parser doesn't show them on the page - text in the source code, but not visible.

Answer (score 3):

1) On FAQ page http://goldendict.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ I found how to add custom styles for the article pages:

> The article text you see is actually an HTML page. It has its own CSS style which can be arbitrarily altered. To do so, you need to create a special text file article-style.css, located in Linux in ~/.goldendict, and in Windows in %APPDATA%\GoldenDict. You can put arbitrary CSS code there.

So I created such style file in the path provided.

2) I added this style to parse span blocks correctly (the way they are used in the page code):

```
.dsl_ex,.dsl_opt{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

After this, you should open an article again and see that the problem is solved.
Example of how the article looks with the error and after fixing styles:
https://ibb.co/jTHesA

---

UPD: I have received the answer in programme support tracker, there is also the more simple solution: https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/issues/1065